# Binary logistic regression after factor reduction in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss

I have about 25 variables on a likert scale which I have subjected to factor reduction and arrived at 8 factors on which 20 variables are loading cumulatively. I wanted to use these factors and 3 demographic variables in a logistic regression test where the dependent variable is binary (yes/no).

How do I use the factors as input in logistic regression test? 
This is to have fewer "variables in the equation" in the output of LR test.

Is multiple response set a way forward?

Please suggest!!

Comment: You want to use 8 latent factors and 3 demographic variables as predictors in a regression.  What exactly are you asking--for suggestions about narrowing down that set of predictors?

Comment: I do not want to include 20+ variables as IV in logistic regression. So I have reduced them to 8 factors with factor reduction. So is it enough now to take means of these variables (loading on each factor) and generate new columns in data view and use these as IV for LR test

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is a way to compute *factor scores*.  Each observation needs to be assigned, based on factor loadings, a score for each of the factors.